# How do i call an ajax file in laravel

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax, laravel

I have an ajax file saved as ajax.php which contains the following code:

```html
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","quiz"); // change here to your data
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Check the number of all questions, if next_id is more than last question, back to first or whatever you want;
$response=mysqli_query($con,"select * from questions");
$number_of_all_questions = mysqli_num_rows($response);

if($_POST['next_id'] == 0){
 // reset to default
 $_SESSION["correct_score"] = 0;
 $_SESSION["not_correct_score"] = 0;
}


if($number_of_all_questions <= $_POST['next_id']){
 // Quiz finished, show results
    echo"<div>
 <h2>Results:</h2>
 <p>Correct answers: {$_SESSION['correct_score']}</p>
 <p>Wrong answers: {$_SESSION['not_correct_score']}</p>

 </div>";



}else{

 // query next question
 $response=mysqli_query($con,"select * from questions WHERE id =(select min(id) from questions where id > {$_POST['next_id']})");
 ?>

 <?php while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($response,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>

  <div id="question_<?= $result['id'] ?>" class='question' data-next-question="<?= $_POST['next_id'] ?>"> <!--check the class for plurals if error occurs-->
   <h2><?= $result['id'].".".$result['question_name'] ?></h2>
   <div class='align'>
    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1' name='1'>
    <label id='ans1' for='radio1'><?= $result['answer1'] ?></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio2' name='2'>
    <label id='ans2' for='radio2'><?= $result['answer2'] ?></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio3' name='3'>
    <label id='ans3' for='radio3'><?= $result['answer3'] ?></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio4' name='4'>
    <label id='ans4' for='radio4'><?= $result['answer4'] ?></label>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <?php /*<input type="button" data-next-question="<?= $_POST['next_id'] ?>" id='next' value='Next!' name='question' class='butt'/> */?>
  </div>
 <?php }?>
<?php }?>
<?php mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

the ajax file contains the code for fetching questions from my database "quiz". I did this using PHP and HTML and it worked fine. now I am shifting it to laravel. the problem is,only plain html is showing in view blade. the questions are not shown in the blade. how can i call this ajax file inside my view blade

Comment: you should move your ajax.php code to controller and access it by routing

Comment: i am new to laravel can you explain as an answer. i will update it with my ajax code

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers and https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing is all the help I can give you, you need to learn basics first

Comment: How do you call this file? Is that an ajax call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should move your php codes in your controller and access it by routes , however you should use eloquent ORM to fetch data from your database and just prepare variables to your blade views and show them.

[here is a tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017)

[laravel docs is another choice](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5)